# Identifying user based on time intervals between keystrokes

Tags: time-series

I am  collecting data which is come from user keystroke (keyboard). I am registering the time passing the one letter to another letter.
For example when user type "ab", I am getting time interval between those 2 letter.

In that way, I am planing to identify user identity.I expect that typing pattern gives me the user identity.

I have collected data (letters and intervals of each letter). But dont know how I follow a path as a next step. Which statistical method should I have follow or apply?

Comment: It depends on your application.  If you're trying to make a tool to identify users from their keystroke time intervals, you're probably best off using a machine learning algorithm, such as naive Bayes, logistic regression, or SVM.  If you're just trying to see if such a thing is rigorously possible, statistical tests are probably better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a record of which key is pressed would greatly increase the amount of information and probably the predictive power of your model.
Assuming that you do not intend to record which key is being pressed and only use elapsed time between keystrokes, a simple method you can follow is performing a series of two-sample tests where user A is compared to all reference users in your database.

For example, you can construct the ecdf (empirical cumulative distribution function) of time intervals for user A and compare against all ecdf's from your database using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. This test produces a p-value for each comparison. It would be wise to carry out multiple tests per pair-comparison using re-sampling techniques. For example, build 1000 ecdfs by randomly choosing a subset of the available data. This way, a distribution of p-values can be obtained for each candidate pairing. The pairing that gives a p-value distribution well-approximating the uniform distribution is the one supporting your null hypothesis i.e. keystrokes being compared come from the same individual.

However, I again stress that having additional information such as which keystroke is being pressed will open up much greater possibilities for user identification, through employing machine learning techniques while employing cross-validation etc.